# Jacobian, volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus

a transformation $$T: (x,y,z))\rightarrow  (x,y+\tan(\alpha z),z),  \alpha \in (0,\pi )$$
$$\Omega = \left\{(x,y,z)  \mid x^2+y^2\leq 1, 0\leq x \leq 2\right\}$$
Find the volume of $$T(\Omega)$$

I think I should get the volume before transformation, then multiplied by the Jacobian
$$V(\Omega)=\pi r^2 h = \pi\cdot 1^2\cdot 2 =2 \pi$$
What makes me feel doubtful is the Jacobian...
let $$\left\{\begin{matrix}u=x
\\ v=y+tan(\alpha z)
\\ w=z
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 
 0 & 1 &  0 \\ 
 0 & -\alpha sec^2(\alpha  w) & 1
\end{vmatrix} $$ 
the Jacobian matrix looks like have nothing to do with alpha
Is there anything went wrong?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Forget about the $x$-coordinate, and make a picture of how $T$ transforms a figure in the $yz$-plane. Can you say whether $T$'s behaviour in terms of change-of-volume _should_ depend at all on $\alpha$?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for your help!! If only looks at yz-plan, the jacobian would be the lower right 2 by 2 matrix, of magnitude 1, so alpha doesn't have effect on the volume change. But does it matter that focusing on yz-plane or not? they should have the same conclusion, right?

Comment: $T$ doesn't affect the $x$-coordinate, so it is essentially a $2$-d map. We know that $T$ doesn't change volumes from the Jacobian, but can you see why if you picture what it does in the $yz$-plane?